# Как посчитать сколько раз встречается слово в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если с клавиатуры вводится строка, например, `слово1 слово2 слово1 слово3`, то как посчитать кол-во слов в строке, чтобы выводился результат вроде `0 0 1 0`?
Думал, это как то с помощью списка сделать можно:

```
C = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
for elem in C:
    print(elem)
```

Но никак не пойму, как реализовать подсчет.

Comment: 1) заводим список совпадений (сначала - пустой); 2) разбиваем текст на слова; 3) для каждого слова в списке проверяем есть ли такой ключ в списке совпадений; 4) если такого индекса нет - сохраняем под данным ключом значение 0; 5) выводим значение, хранящееся в списке совпадений по данному ключу; 6) увеличиваем значение по данному слову-ключу на 1

Comment: @BOPOH, спасибо. не знаю только как реализовывается пункт 3 и 4 - никогда не писал на питоне. сегодня только понадобилось решить задачу. можете, пожалуйста, пример кода привести?

Comment: 1) цикл по словам: `for word in word_list:` 2) проверить ключ в словаре `word_count = {}; if word in word_count:` 3) создать индекс в словаре: `word_count[word] = 0`. Осталось из кусочков программу создать

Comment: @BOPOH, спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант подсчета через словарь `defaultdict`

Попробуйте это:

```
from collections import defaultdict

words = "слово1 слово2 слово1 слово3 слово2 Вася слово1"
word_list = words.split()

word_count_dict = defaultdict(int)

for word in word_list:
    print(word, word_count_dict[word])
    word_count_dict[word] += 1
```

Результат:

```
слово1 0
слово2 0
слово1 1
слово3 0
слово2 1
Вася 0
слово1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> input_data = 'слово1 слово2 слово1 слово3'
>>> words = input_data.split()
>>> counter = Counter()  # получаем словарь. ключ - слово, значение - количество повторов
>>> print(' '.join(str(counter[word]) for word in words))
'2 1 2 1'
```

Comment: вывод неправильный, надо выводить сколько это слово встречалось раньше, а не всего. Т.е. первый раз слово "слово1" ни разу не встречалось, значит надо вывести 0. Второй раз "слово1" встречалось уже 1 раз, значит надо вывести 1. Если потом еще раз встретится слово "слово1", надо будет вывести 2 и т.д. А у вас показывает уже готовый результат. В задаче же написано какой должен быть вывод (0 0 1 0)

Comment: @BOPOH прав. вывод другой требуется. но спасибо большое за пример